# R mutate dataframe based on rows meeting certain condition in each row

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I'm looking to mutate a new row in a dataframe, which is based on row values being within a certain range of an existing row.

Something like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "a" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 15, 22, 60),
  "b" = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  10, 11)
)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(c = mean(if(~a <= a, ~b)))
```

Where "~a" refers to the whole column of "a" values, and "a" refers to the specific row that is being mutated.

Edit:
So the expected output of c would be:
(2, [average of "b" values where "a" is less than the first "a" value]
2.5 [average of "b" values where "a" is less than the second "a" value]
and so on).
In practice, I have multiple "if" conditions, so it's not just a cumulative sum/average.

I have found solutions online where the if statement is specific (e.g. mutate if ~a < 5), but not based on the present rowwise value of a.

Comment: Can you share your expected output? It is unclear now what you are aiming

Comment: As an example of the calculation I'm trying to do, the first value of c would be:
for all values in column a less than or equal to the current value (1), average the corresponding "b" values (in the first case, just the "2").

The second value would be the average of all "b" values where the corresponding "a" value is less than or equal to the second "a" value. 

And so on. 
What I'm trying to do in practice has multiple conditions, so I'm not sure cumulative sum/average functions would work.

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate down the `a` column. You can do this inside `mutate` using `sapply`

```r
df %>%
  mutate(c = sapply(a, \(x) mean(b[a <= x])))
#>     a  b   c
#> 1   1  2 2.0
#> 2   2  3 2.5
#> 3   3  4 3.0
#> 4   4  5 3.5
#> 5   5  6 4.0
#> 6   8  7 4.5
#> 7   9  8 5.0
#> 8  15  9 5.5
#> 9  22 10 6.0
#> 10 60 11 6.5
```

Comment: or we could use `purrr`s `map_vec`: `df %>%
  mutate(c = map_vec(a, ~ mean(b[a <= .x])))`

Comment: That's nice @TarJae - like a safer version of `sapply`

Answer (score 4):

Since your `a` is sorted already (at least your example is presented in that way), you are equivalently computing the roll mean of `b` with varying number of samples (depending on `a`'s position)

You can try `cummean` like below

```
df %>%
  mutate(c = cummean(b))
```

which should give

```
    a  b   c
1   1  2 2.0
2   2  3 2.5
3   3  4 3.0
4   4  5 3.5
5   5  6 4.0
6   8  7 4.5
7   9  8 5.0
8  15  9 5.5
9  22 10 6.0
10 60 11 6.5
```

---

## For general cases (unsorted `a`)

For example, if `a` is unsorted, you can use the following code

```
df %>%
  mutate(c = colMeans(b * NA^!outer(a, a, `<=`), TRUE))
```

or more efficient (thanks for comments from @Onyambu)

```
df %>%
  mutate(c=cummean(b[o<-order(a)])[match(row_number(), o)])
```

which gives the same output

```
    a  b   c
1   1  2 2.0
2   2  3 2.5
3   3  4 3.0
4   4  5 3.5
5   5  6 4.0
6   8  7 4.5
7   9  8 5.0
8  15  9 5.5
9  22 10 6.0
10 60 11 6.5
```

For an unsorted example

```
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(
  "a" = sample(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 15, 22, 60)),
  "b" = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
)
```

we can achieve

```
    a  b        c
1  22  2 6.222222
2   4  3 5.500000
3   9  4 6.142857
4   1  5 5.000000
5   2  6 5.500000
6   5  7 5.800000
7   3  8 6.333333
8  60  9 6.500000
9   8 10 6.500000
10 15 11 6.750000
```

Comment: seems you are doing `cummean`... you've already loaded `dplyr` as you are using `mutate`, `cummean` should be visible

Comment: I wasn't sure we could assume ordering, though if we can this will be faster.

Comment: @Onyambu aha, I was not aware of that function, thanks for the simplification!

Comment: @AllanCameron yes, I admit that this is a special treatment for a special case, and this approach won't work if `a` is unsorted.

Comment: @AllanCameron I added an other code for general cases.

Comment: Outer is very innefficient it has O(n^2). You still should use `cummean`: ie `df %>%mutate(c=cummean(b[o<-order(a)])[match(row_number(), o)])` which would have at most `O(nlog n)`

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, that makes sense. now your option is added into the answer, thanks again!